# Jquery set timeout

Tags: jquery, timeout, settimeout

I want to add a `timeout` to the following code

```
var faderIndex = 0,
        faders = $('.fadey');

    function nextFade() {
        $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
            faderIndex++;
            if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
                faderIndex = 0;
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
        });
    }
    nextFade();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gpQYW/501/

Do you have any suggestions on how to accomplish that ?

Comment: For what purpose? The implementation you have now using callbacks is a much better pattern to use.

Comment: Check out http://api.jquery.com/delay/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    timeset=setTimeout(function() {
//do something 
    }, 8000);

     timeset=setTimeout(function() {
    var faderIndex = 0,
            faders = $('.fadey');

        function nextFade() {
            $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                faderIndex++;
                if (faderIndex >= faders.length)
                    faderIndex = 0;
                $(faders[faderIndex]).fadeIn(1000, nextFade);
            });

        }
        nextFade();

    }, 8000);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use javascript timeout

```
var counter = 0;
tid = setTimeout(mycode, 3000);
                function mycode() {
                    counter++;
                    if (counter > 500) {
                        clearTimeout(tid);
                    tid=null;
                    return;
                    }

        tid = setTimeout(mycode, 10);
                }
```